# Spacing between header and text

Tags: spacing, fancyhdr

I have a pretty simple report document that I made myself (I usually use templates)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times new roman
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
      \fontsize{20}{20}%
      \selectfont}
\font\myfont=cmr14 at 40pt
\title{\centering sample}

\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/itu.jpeg}
}
\fancyheadoffset[loh,ro]{20}
\fancyhead[L]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont \today} }
\author{John\\
   \texttt{rrtf@itu.dk}
\and DOn\\
    \texttt{dddd@itu.dk}
}
\pretitle{%
\begin{center}
    \title{}{\Huge \ Ratcheting in Lorawan}
    
    
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/ratchet.png}\\
  
  \end{center}

}
\date{November 2021}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
I"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem  accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab  illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt  explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut  odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione  voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum  quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam  eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat  voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam  corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?  Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse  quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo  voluptas nulla pariatur?"

\subsection{LoRaWAN}
LoRaWAN builds on top of LoRa, which acts as the physical layer. LoRa is built to enable long range communication in otherwise rural areas, and also have very low power requirements \ci\usepackage{graphicx}te{semtech}.
LoRaWAN builds on top of the LoRa network modulation technique for long range communication. the infrastructure of LoRaWAN requires the existence of three different servers:
\begin{itemize}
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem  accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab  illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt  explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut  odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione  voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum  quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam  eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat  voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam  corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?  Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse  quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo  voluptas nulla pariatur?"
\subsubsection{LoRaWAN join}

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem  accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab  illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt  explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut  odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione  voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum  quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam  eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat  voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam  corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?  Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse  quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo  voluptas nulla pariatur?"
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figures/JOINlorawan.jpg}
    \caption{a nice plot}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}


\subsection{Security properties and threat model}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Now, the current problem is that the header I have appears really close to the top text of any page.

Like this:

[image]

and if there is a image it looks like this:

[image]

Also I have a front page, that I want to stay where it is, i.e the image and title there should not be moved down.

I first tried using this line to make some more top padding:

```
\usepackage[top=1.5in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt]{geometry}
```

But this just pushes everything down on the page, including the header. plus, it also pushes the front page down.

I then tried this:

```
\setlength{\headsep}{1in}
```

This works, but also pushes down my front page, which makes it look wierd.

What can one do?

Comment: 1) It would be nice if you supplied a working document that we can compile without having to make all kinds of changes to get rid of the errors.
2) If you change `headheight` in the `geometry` call, it might be best to use the `includehead` option also.

Comment: Also check your log file to see if it complains about `\headheight too small`.

Answer (score 3):

Using

`\usepackage[top=0.5in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in, headheight=50pt, footskip=35.4pt, includehead]{geometry}`  and this `.jpg`

[image: crop]

as itu logo. It is an image 224x82 px.

The output of your code will be

[image: a]

If your logo has a larger height crop it or change `headheight`.